# sum two columns as totals then minus the two totals together

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, variance, rollup

I have this script:

```
SELECT

  ISNULL([name], 'Total') AS [name]
, [Yesterday]
, [Today]
, [variance]

FROM 
(
  SELECT 
[name],
SUM([yesterday]) AS [yesterday],
SUM([today]) AS [today],
sum(variance) as Variance

  FROM mytable
      GROUP BY [name] WITH ROLLUP
 ) AS DT
```

Which returns this table:

```
name  |yesterday|today|variance
john  | 3       |4    | 0.33
smith | 4       |5    |0.25
daniel| 5       |2    |-0.6
total | 12      |11   |-0.02
```

where the variance total should actually be: (11-12)/12 = -0.833

How can I get my script to produce that outcome rather than a total of the variance column?

the data expected would be:

```
name  |yesterday|today|variance
john  | 3       |4    | 0.33
smith | 4       |5    |0.25
daniel| 5       |2    |-0.6
total | 12      |11   |-0.833
```

Comment: Could you provided the data on which you are expecting the given outcome?

Comment: i have updated. everything basically stays the same but that one number that needs to be calculated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?:

```
SELECT

  ISNULL([name], 'Total') AS [name]
, [Yesterday]
, [Today]
, [variance]

FROM 
(
  SELECT 
[name],
SUM([yesterday]) AS [yesterday],
SUM([today]) AS [today],
((SUM([today]) -SUM([yesterday]))/SUM([yesterday])) as Variance

  FROM mytable
      GROUP BY [name] WITH ROLLUP
 ) AS DT
```

Comment: no as that would calculate the rows on the two columns only, not the actual total at the bottom of the returned query...